# Recognize a string in a txt from two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want my program to read lines in a txt and to recognize a string using two columns, i tried with for row in column1 and column2 but it isn't working and i don't really know why, here is the code.(Here i want to print the 5 first letters when it recognize the string, but later i will put those five letters in a list).

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np

link = "excelfilett.txt"
file = open(link, "r")
frames_load = []
is_count_frames_load = False
for line in file:
    if "[Interface1]" in line:
        is_count_frames_load = True
    if is_count_frames_load== True:
        frames_load.append(line)
    if "[EthernetComNeed]" in line:
        break

number_of_rows_load = len(frames_load) -1
header_load = re.split(r'\t', frames_load[0])
number_of_columns_load = len(header_load)

frame_array_load = np.full((number_of_rows_load, number_of_columns_load), 0)
df_frame_array_load = pd.DataFrame(frame_array_load)
df_frame_array_load.columns= header_load

for row in range(number_of_rows_load):
    frame_row_load = re.split(r'\t', frames_load[row])
    for position in range(len(frame_row_load)):
        df_frame_array_load.iloc[row, position] = frame_row_load[position]
print(df_frame_array_load)
df_frame_array_load["[Name]"] = df_frame_array_load["[End1]"] + '\t' +  df_frame_array_load["[End2]"]
df_frame_array_load["[Name2]"] = df_frame_array_load["[End2]"] + '\t' +  df_frame_array_load["[End1]"]

print(df_frame_array_load["[Name]"])
print(df_frame_array_load["[Name2]"])

link = "excelfilett.txt"
file = open(link, "r")
frames_path = []
is_count_frames_path = False
for line in file:
    if "[Routing Paths]" in line:
        is_count_frames_path = True
    if is_count_frames_path== True:
        for row in df_frame_array_load["[Name]"] and df_frame_array_load["[Name2]"]:
            if row in line:
                print(row)
                print(line[0:4])
            if "[EthernetComNeed]" in line:
                break
    if "[EthernetComConfig]" in line:
        break
```

What I want as output is to print the 5 first letters in the lines of the txt. I'm using when it recognize a string, for example, when "S1\tS2" is in the line of the txt, it will print me the 5 first letters, so "FL_1", the two columns contains string as "S1\tS2" and the inverse (like "S2\tS1"), it is the point of the line where I have an issue, it gives me

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

in the line "for row in column1 and column2:".

Comment: Could you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: Oh yes, i forgot to put it, i quickly edit it.

Comment: Its always good to provide some python code that can be copy pasted in python, otherwise even if one can read your explanation it's cumbersome to reproduce it.

Comment: I gave all the code i did for the python program, tell me if you also want to see the txt and the columns.

Comment: Hi JoNeen, welcome on SO. I hope you're going to find an answer for your question. It is a good idea to read something about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [mcve2](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it isn't possible to read rows on two columns at one time, i just make my program read the two columns separately, here is what i changed:

```
link = "excelfilett.txt"
file = open(link, "r")
frames_path = []
is_count_frames_path = False
for line in file:
    if "[Routing Paths]" in line:
        is_count_frames_path = True
    if is_count_frames_path== True:
        for row in df_frame_array_load["[Name]"]:
            if row in line:
                print(row)
                print(line[0:4])
            if "[EthernetComNeed]" in line:
                break
        for row in df_frame_array_load["[Name2]"]:
            if row in line:
                print(row)
                print(line[0:4])
    if "[EthernetComConfig]" in line:
        break
```